# Vue components stop updating when page is translated by Google translate

Tags: vue.js

When pages with Vue components are translated via chrome's translate option, the vue components stops re rendering and updating the view.

Ex: Translate https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Handling-User-Input on chrome using the translate option from chromes's context menu into a different language, the reverse message demo stops working.

Since Google translate plugin updates DOM outside of Vue's control, this is sort of expected. Looking for any work arounds that let both co-exist. The sections can be marked with "notranslate" class but that would mean it is no longer translatable.

React inspite of being based on virtual DOM, works even with DOM being modified by translate plugin.

[image: Gif of Google translate affecting the demo of Vue site]

Comment: I didn't have this problem. Chrome 65, Debian Stretch, translated to Korean. Perhaps there's more going on here than just VueJS. I see, I'm an idiot. Problem definitely exists. This is why I don't work in QA.

Comment: Google Chrome - Version 65 on OSX

Comment: BTW `React` also doesn't play well with `Google Translate`: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use the Vue special attributes **key** (as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)) and **ref** (as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)).

Here it is an example I did, starting from the link you provide above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vue.js Reverse Example</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
<div id="app-5" class="demo">
  <!-- Adding Vue attributes here -->
  <p :key="message" ref="msg">{{ message }}</p>
  <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      // vm.$refs.msg.innerText retrieves the translated content
      this.message = vm.$refs.msg.innerText.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
  
</html>
```

As you may notice, the DOM element where you'd like to maintain the Vue reactive behavior (i.e.: the reverse operation here), has been enriched with both a `key` attribute and a `ref` one.
The idea here is to use:

- `:key` to force replacement of the element instead of reusing it;
- `ref` to register a reference to the element: it is used in `reverseMessage` method in order to get the translated innerText content after the Google translation is performed.

For sure, this workaround would affect the performance, but at least it provides the expected behavior (i.e.: the reverse function properly working also after a page translation).